# A question about formatting a DataFrame for use with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a solution to a PDE that I would like to plot. I have seen two ways to do this in the documentation, one of which works for me, and one that doesn't. No error is generated. One simply results in the correct plot (a sin wave), and the other generates a line with slope of 1. The second method may be useful to know in the future, even if I have code that works now. Thanks in advance.

**Working solution:**

```
plt.plot(arange(0, 16*pi, Dt), u[:, index])
plt.show()
```

This is great and super simple! The below method was found in the matplotlib documentation as well, but it yields an incorrect plot. I'd like to know my error:

**Non working solution:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'t':arange(0, 16*pi, Dt), 'u':u[:,index]})
plt.plot('t', 'u', data=df)
plt.show()
```

---

**full code for context**

```
from math import sin, cos, pi, fabs, log10, ceil, floor
from numpy import arange, zeros
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


#function applies periodic boundary condition where h is the period
def apply_pbc(f, i, Dx, M, h):
    f[i][0] = f[i][int(h/Dx)]
    f[i][int((M + Dx)/Dx)] = f[i][int((M + Dx)/Dx - 1)]

    return f

# function for finding an index associated with
# a particular data point of interest for plotting
# or other analysis
def find_index(start, stop, step, x):
    counter = len(arange(start, stop, step))
    for i in arange(counter):
        x_i = start + i*step
        if abs(x - x_i) < pow(10, -15):
            index = i
            print("x = ", x_i, "@index j = ", i)
            break

    return index

#main body
if __name__ == "__main__":

    #constants
    a = 0.25
    b = 0.25
    c = 1

    #period of boundary conditions
    h = 4*pi

    #space and time endpoints
    M = 4*pi
    N = 16*pi

    #mesh
    Dx = 0.005*4*pi
    Dt = (0.25*Dx)/c

    #simplification of numeric method
    r = (Dt*pow(c,2))/pow(Dx,2)

    #get size of data set
    rows = len(arange(0, N, Dt))
    cols = len(arange(-Dx, M, Dx))

    #initiate solution arrays
    u = zeros((rows, cols))
    v = zeros((rows, cols))

    #apply initial conditions
    for j in range(cols):
        x = -Dx + j*Dx
        u[0][j] = cos(x)
        v[0][j] = 0


    #solve
    for i in range(1, rows):
        for j in range(1, cols - 1):
            u[i][j] = u[i-1][j] + v[i-1][j]*Dt \
                    + (a/2)*(u[i-1][j+1] - 2*u[i-1][j] + u[i-1][j-1])

            v[i][j] = v[i-1][j] \
                    + r*(u[i-1][j+1] - 2*u[i-1][j] + u[i-1][j-1]) \
                    + (b/2)*(v[i-1][j+1] - 2*v[i-1][j] + v[i-1][j-1])
        apply_pbc(u, i, Dx, M, h)
        apply_pbc(v, i, Dx, M, h)

    print("done")

    #we want to plot the solution u(t,x), where x = pi
    index = find_index(-Dx, M + Dx, Dx, pi)

    df = pd.DataFrame({'t':arange(0,16*pi, Dt), 'u':u[:,index]})
    plt.plot('t', 'x', data=df)
    # plt.plot(arange(0, 16*pi, Dt), u[:, index])
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation of plt.plot()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html):

> ### Plotting labelled data
>
> There's a convenient way for plotting objects with labelled data (i.e.
>   data that can be accessed by index obj['y']). Instead of giving the
>   data in x and y, you can provide the object in the data parameter and
>   just give the labels for x and y:
>
> > > ```
> > > plot('xlabel', 'ylabel', data=obj)
> > > ```

I think there is just a typo in your code. In the full code you provide, this is the line that makes the plot:

```
plt.plot('t', 'x', data=df)
```

which does indeed give

[image]

while changing to

```
plt.plot('t', 'u', data=df)
```

works as expected:
[image]

Last bit of the code:

> ```
> df = pd.DataFrame({'t':arange(0,16*pi, Dt), 'u':u[:,index]})
> plt.plot('t', 'x', data=df)  # <-- 'x' instead of 'u'
> # plt.plot(arange(0, 16*pi, Dt), u[:, index])
> plt.show()
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I may be blind but I don't see a typo. If there is one, I think it must be in the declaration of the DataFrame object... but I see none there. That leads me to believe that I am misunderstanding how to declare it.

Comment: maybe I am misunderstanding, but you are not plotting column 'u' of your dataframe in your code

Comment: Perfect! I see your edit. Indeed I was misunderstanding. I thought that 't' and 'u' or 'x' where just labels that are not connected to the data=df. I didn't think it mattered what I labeled them, but it looks like they need to be consistent.